# How to find number of items which contains specific string using js filter method

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I would like to find number of items which has specific text using js filter method.

```
var num = 
[
  {
    "name": "name1 ",
    "category": "test"
  },
  {
    "name": " name2",
    "category": "test2"
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "category": "cat3"
  },
  {
    "name": "name 4",
    "category": "cat 4"
  }
];
```

num is an object;

Now, i want to find number of categories which has text 'cat'. So i want the result 2. How to get that using filter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how you can do it

```js
var num = 
[
  {
    "name": "name1 ",
    "category": "test"
  },
  {
    "name": " name2",
    "category": "test2"
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "category": "cat3"
  },
  {
    "name": "name 4",
    "category": "cat 4"
  }
];

console.log( num.filter(i => i.category.indexOf("cat") === 0).length )
```

Answer (score 1):

> num is an object;

True, but specifically it's an *array* object.

You *could* use `filter` for this, but [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) would be the more appropriate option if you don't want the array of matching results:

```
var result = num.reduce(function(sum, entry) => sum + (entry.category.includes("cat") ? 1 : 0), 0);
```

Live Example:

```js
var num = 
[
  {
    "name": "name1 ",
    "category": "test"
  },
  {
    "name": " name2",
    "category": "test2"
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "category": "cat3"
  },
  {
    "name": "name 4",
    "category": "cat 4"
  }
];
var result = num.reduce(function(sum, entry) {
    return sum + (entry.category.includes("cat") ? 1 : 0);
}, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Or with ES2015+:

```js
const num = 
[
  {
    "name": "name1 ",
    "category": "test"
  },
  {
    "name": " name2",
    "category": "test2"
  },
  {
    "name": "name3",
    "category": "cat3"
  },
  {
    "name": "name 4",
    "category": "cat 4"
  }
];
const result = num.reduce((sum, entry) => sum + (entry.category.includes("cat") ? 1 : 0), 0);
console.log(result);
```

Or of course, a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple. In ES6 the solution would be this:

```
const countOfCats = num.filter(entry => entry.category.match('cat')).length;
```

Another way could be:

```
const countOfCats = num.filter(entry => entry.contains("cat")).length;
```